# Can someone show me how to plot Uniform distribution on matlab?

Tags: matlab, distribution, uniform

I already have this code , which I kinda borrowed from Gaussian distribution and kinda modified it  .
which is as below

```
[f,x]=hist(rand(1000000,1),50);%# create histogram from a normal distribution.
g=1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-0.5*x.^2);%# pdf of the normal distribution
%#METHOD 2: DIVIDE BY AREA
figure(2)
bar(x,f/trapz(x,f));hold on
plot(x,1,'r');hold off .
```

Now is there  anything I can change in it to make the red line without separations or no? 
Let me know .
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the red line to be? If you want a constant red line at one, you should use

```
plot(x,ones(size(x)),'r-')
```

If you want to plot this against the uniform distribution, normalised to one,

```
[f,x]=hist(rand(1000000,1),50);
bar(x,f/trapz(x,f));hold on
plot(x,ones(size(x)),'r-');
hold off
```

Where the division by the integral of the function gives an area under the distribution equal to one.

If you want a Gaussian distribution directly, you should get random numbers from `randn` instead of rand, e.g.

```
[f,x]=hist(randn(1000000,1),50)
bar(x,f/trapz(x,f))
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted the first .